# Как организовать индексированный поиск по локальной сети используя catfish

Tags: поиск, сервер, сеть, ubuntu

Установил catfish. В ней используются несколько методов поиска. Как я понял в данном случае подходящий это "tracker". Указать сетевой источник (самба папка) не получается. Подскажите кто сталкивался.

Изначально искал персональный поиск Яндекса, но он только под windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Подключаете самба-папку (например, в /home/user/mnt/samba-server);
2. в catfish выбираете данную папку и метод find;
3. пуск